# Pass through arugments object

Tags: jquery

I want to perfectly wrap jquery post and get. Is it somehow possible to pass through the arguments object?

```
function myPost(){
   return $.post(arguments);
}
```

Doing the above doesn't work because it is passed as an object.

Otherwise I have to wrap this somehow

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            dataType: type,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function myPost() {
    return $.post.apply($, arguments);
}
```

With `apply` you can pass an array, which will be used for calling the function with the first argument set to the first array element, the second to the second, etc.

#### ES6 Spread Operator

With the ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) you can do it like this:

```
function myPost() {
    return $.post(...arguments);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. There is always a way in JS.